# Is it possible to do boolean assertions with raku regex?

Tags: regex, raku, rakudo

In the [apocalypses](https://raku.org/archive/doc/design/apo/A05.html), there are some words about boolean assertions:

```
<( code )>            # call code as boolean assertion
```

However, I cannot make it work.

```
say "9471" ~~ m:g/ (\d) <($0 > 5)> /
```

I expect to only match numbers greater than 5, but I get a compile error.

Which is the correct syntax (if exists), or any alternative to do some boolean assertion?

Comment: Note that those are historical documents. The language changed a lot after they were written.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Boolean condition check](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regex_Boolean_condition_check)

```
$ raku -e 'say "9471" ~~ m:g/ (\d) <?{ $0 > 5 }> /'
(｢9｣
 0 => ｢9｣ ｢7｣
 0 => ｢7｣)
```

Comment: I'd say this is a documentation issue (can recall having the same quandary myself) ... perhaps raise as an issue to make the <{}> family more prominent...?

Comment: @p6steve: By all means, please do!

Comment: Ahhh - just being lazy - done now. https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/3705